# Command line equivalent of `getrusage()`

Tags: bash, command-line, io

I'd like to track **disk io** that a **given command** does. `getrusage()` can be used in C; can I get same in command line somehow?

`time` and `times` show user and system time spent, the latter including own/children breakdown, how about all the other bits, like disk io, spwap, peak memory?

An example:

```
[user@hsot ~]$ time sqlite3 haha.db vacuum

real    1m6.439s
user    0m7.407s
sys     0m10.000s

# what I'd like in addition
blocks in    1228349
blocks out   34523
maxrss       45634953
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally something like this would be built into bash (or whatever shell you are using). Unfortunately there is no such thing AFAIK.

But it's trivial to create your own wrapper using getrusage():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    system(argv[1]);
    struct rusage ru;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, &ru);
    printf("\nblocks in:\t%li\nblocks out:\t%li\nmaxrss:\t\t%li\n",
            ru.ru_inblock, ru.ru_oublock, ru.ru_maxrss);
}
```

compile it:

```
$ gcc -o process_io process_io.c
```

And use it:

```
$ ./process_io "dd if=/dev/urandom of=foobar bs=1k count=10000"
10000+0 records in
10000+0 records out
10240000 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.922149 s, 11.1 MB/s

blocks in:      0
blocks out:     80128
maxrss:         1676
```

Comment: Awesome... is rusage guaranteed to be 0 before `system()` call? Also, are "grandchildren" counted in?

Comment: getrusage() is 0 when the process is created. system() starts a shell, which might do a little I/O itself (reading configuration files). Other than that, there are no other children of this process.

Comment: You could fork()/exec() and waitpid() instead of system() to avoid the little shell overhead and get exact results.

Comment: Still awesome. Still works. Also found /usr/bin/time -v for Linux and /usr/bin/time -l for Darwin.

Answer (score 1):

Following chris'es answer I have this in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import resource
import subprocess


bsel = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
bchl = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:]).communicate()
for i in range(10**7): pass  # test children/self independence
asel = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
achl = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)

print("""--child--
user\t%s
sys\t%s
mem\t%s
inb\t%s
oub\t%s
maj\t%s
nivcsw\t%s""" % (achl.ru_utime - bchl.ru_utime,
                 achl.ru_stime - bchl.ru_stime,
                 achl.ru_maxrss,
                 achl.ru_inblock - bchl.ru_inblock,
                 achl.ru_oublock - bchl.ru_oublock,
                 achl.ru_majflt - bchl.ru_majflt,
                 achl.ru_nivcsw - bchl.ru_nivcsw))

print("""--self--
user\t%s
sys\t%s
mem\t%s
inb\t%s
oub\t%s
maj\t%s
nivcsw\t%s""" % (asel.ru_utime - bsel.ru_utime,
                 asel.ru_stime - bsel.ru_stime,
                 asel.ru_maxrss,
                 asel.ru_inblock - bsel.ru_inblock,
                 asel.ru_oublock - bsel.ru_oublock,
                 asel.ru_majflt - bsel.ru_majflt,
                 asel.ru_nivcsw - bsel.ru_nivcsw))
```

it seems to work :)

P.S. I am still looking for clarification of self vs children vs grandchildren. New answers are welcome too :)

Answer (score 0):

iostat displays system write/read to discs. Sadly not for a specific process, but system wide, but if you are on your development machine, I guess it might be okey.

Comment: I do use `iostat` and even `iotop`. You are correct that some info can be gleamed. Ideally I'd like something non-intrusive, like `time` that would allow me to multitask.